# Asymptotic time complexity of inserting n elements to a binary heap already containing n elements

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, asymptotic-complexity, binary-heap

Suppose we have a binary heap of n elements and wish to insert n more elements(not necessarily one after other). What would be the total time required for this?

I think it's theta (n logn) as one insertion takes logn.

Comment: I think the size of the existing heap should enter the result somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming we are given:

- priority queue implemented by standard binary heap **H** (**implemented on array**)
- **n** current size of heap

We have following **insertion** properties:

- W(n) = WorstCase(n) = Θ(lg n) (Theta). -> W(n)=Ω(lg n) and W(n)=O(lg n)
- A(n) = AverageCase(n) = Θ(lg n) (Theta). -> W(n)=Ω(lg n) and W(n)=O(lg n)
- B(n) = BestCase(n) = Θ(1) (Theta). -> W(n)=Ω(1) and W(n)=O(1)

So for *every case*, we have

- T(n) = Ω(1) and T(n) = O(lg n)

WorstCase is when, we insert new minimal value, so up-heap has to travel whole branch.

BestCase is when, for minimal-heap (heap with minimal on top) we insert BIG (biggest on updated branch) value (so up-heap stops immediately).

You've asked about series of n operations on heap containing already n elements,
it's size will grow

```
from n to 2*n
```

what asymptotically is ...

```
n=Θ(n)
2*n=Θ(n)
```

What simplifies our equations. (We don't have to worry about growth of *n* , as it's growth is by constant factor).

So, we have "for n insertions" of operation:

- Xi(n) = X_for_n_insertions(n)

  - Wi(n) = Θ(n lg n)
  - Ai(n) = Θ(n lg n)
  - Bi(n) = Θ(n)
- it implies, for "all case":

  - Ti(n) = Ω(n) and Ti(n) = O(n lg n)

P.S. For displaying Theta Θ , Omega Ω symbols, you need to have UTF-8 installed/be compatible.

Answer (score 6):

given : heap of n elements and n more elements to be inserted. So in the end there will be 2*n elements. since heap can be created in 2 ways 1. Successive insertion and 2. Build heap method. Amoung these build heap method takes O(n) time to construct heap which is explained in 
[How can building a heap be O(n) time complexity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755721/build-heap-complexity). so total time required is O(2*n) which is same as O(n)

Answer (score 1):

its not theeta(nlogn)...  its order(nlogn) since  some of the insertions can take less  then exact logn time...     therefore for n insertions it will take time <=nlogn

**=>  time complexity=O(nlogn)**