# space complexity of merge sort using array

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, mergesort

This algorithm is of mergesort, I know this may be looking weird to you but my main focus is on calculating space complexity of this algorithm.

If we look at the recurrence tree of mergesort function and try to trace the algorithm then the stack size will be `log(n)`. But since `merge` function is also there inside the `mergesort` which is creating two arrays of size `n/2`, `n/2` , then first should I find the space complexity of recurrence relation and then, should I add in that `n/2 + n/2` that will become `O(log(n) + n)`.

I know the answer, but I am confused in the process. Can anyone tell me correct procedure?

This confusion is due to merge function which is not recursive but called in a recursive function

And why we are saying that space complexity will be `O(log(n) + n)` and by the definition of recursive function space complexity, we usually calculate the height of recursive tree

```
Merge(Leftarray, Rightarray, Array) {
    nL <- length(Leftarray)
    nR <- length(Rightarray)
    i <- j <- k <- 0
    while (i < nL && j < nR) {
        if (Leftarray[i] <= Rightarray[j])
            Array[k++] <- Leftarray[i++]
        else
            Array[k++] <- Rightarray[j++]
    }
    while (i < nL) {
        Array[k++] <- Leftarray[i++]
    }
    while (j < nR) {
        Array[k++] <- Rightarray[j++]
    }    
}  

Mergesort(Array) {
    n <- length(Array)
    if (n < 2)
        return
    mid <- n / 2
    Leftarray <- array of size (mid)
    Rightarray <- array of size (n-mid)
    for i <- 0 to mid-1
        Leftarray[i] <- Array[i]
    for i <- mid to n-1
        Right[i-mid] <- Array[mid]
    Mergesort(Leftarray)
    Mergesort(Rightarray)
    Merge(Leftarray, Rightarray) 
}
```

Comment: A mergesort implementation should allocate *one* scratch array of size N or N/2, and then reuse the same scratch array for ALL of the merges.

Comment: **Error:** "*Rightarray*" is not defined... (usual error) Also, if this is C, where are the return types, semi-colons, brackets of *for-loops*, etc.? Is this pseudocode?...

Comment: @Ruks OP gave the pseudocode

Comment: @suvojit_007 It begs the question, why the C tag if the actual question has absolutely *nothing* to do with C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge sort space and time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170183/merge-sort-space-and-time-complexity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MergeSort time Complexity is O(nlgn) which is a fundamental knowledge. Merge Sort space complexity will always be O(n) including with arrays. If you draw the space tree out, it will seem as though the space complexity is O(nlgn). However, as the code is a Depth First code, you will always only be expanding along one branch of the tree, therefore, the total space usage required will always be bounded by O(3n) = O(n).

For example, if you draw the space tree out, it seems like it is O(nlgn)

```
                         16                                 | 16
                        /  \                              
                       /    \
                      /      \
                     /        \
                    8          8                            | 16
                   / \        / \
                  /   \      /   \
                 4     4    4     4                         | 16
                / \   / \  / \   / \
               2   2 2   2.....................             | 16
              / \  /\ ........................
             1  1  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1              | 16
```

where height of tree is O(logn) => Space complexity is O(nlogn + n) = O(nlogn). However, this is not the case in the actual code as it does not execute in parallel. For example, in the case where N = 16, this is how the code for mergesort executes. N = 16.

```
                       16
                      /
                     8
                    /
                   4
                 /
                2
               / \
              1   1
```

notice how number of space used is 32 = 2n = 2*16 < 3n

Then it merge upwards

```
                       16
                      /
                     8
                    /
                   4
                 /  \
                2    2
                    / \                
                   1   1
```

which is 34 < 3n. Then it merge upwards

```
                       16
                      /
                     8
                    / \
                   4   4
                      /
                     2
                    / \ 
                   1   1
```

36 < 16 * 3 = 48

then it merge upwards

```
                       16
                      / \
                     8  8
                       / \
                      4   4
                         / \
                        2   2
                            /\
                           1  1
```

16 + 16 + 14 = 46 < 3*n = 48

in a larger case, n = 64

```
                 64
                /  \
               32  32
                   / \
                  16  16
                      / \
                     8  8
                       / \
                      4   4
                         / \
                        2   2
                            /\
                           1  1
```

which is 64*3 <= 3*n = 3*64

You can prove this by induction for the general case.

Therefore, space complexity is always bounded by O(3n) = O(n) even if you implement with arrays as long as you clean up used space after merging and not execute code in parallel but sequential.

Example of my implementation is given below:

Comment: Shamelessly copied from here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342890/merge-sort-time-and-space-complexity

Answer (score 1):

This implementation of `MergeSort` is quite inefficient in memory space and has some bugs:

- the memory is not freed, I assume you rely on garbage collection.
- the target array `Array` is not passed to `Merge` by `MergeSort`.

Extra space in the amount of the size of the `Array` is allocated by `MergeSort` for each recursion level, so at least twice the size of the initial array (**2*N**) is required, if the garbage collection is optimal, for example if it uses reference counts, and up to **N*log2(N)** space is used if the garbage collector is lazy. This is much more than required, as a careful implementation can use as little as **N/2** extra space.

Comment: if i am not passing the target array to merge function than how can this affect the space complexity?
Those statements  take same memory whether you execute them in merge or mergesort

Comment: will memory not be freed automatically for leftarray and rightarray when the recursive call finishes for that particular function say in any step between the execution of program  
Then it will be very much inefficient with respect to space and there will be large number of memory loacation that will be  allocated for left and right subarrays(for every recursive call)
Is   i am right ? or you want to say something else

Comment: I am eagerly waiting for you to be online so that you can answer my question thanku very much in advance, I got your point but i have small above doubts please help

Comment: @newby: not passing the target array to `Merge` is just a mistake, the function does expect a third argument. You originally tagged your question as `c`, allocated objects are not freed automatically in C, unlike Java, you must free them explicitly when they are no longer needed. Regarding the number of allocations, you are definitely making too many calls: a more efficient version would allocate a single temporary array and pass it to an auxiliary function `MergeSortInternal` that would call itself recursively. This would reduce the space complexity to **O(N)** in a single allocation call.