# Why siftDown is better than siftUp in heapify?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

To build a MAX heap tree, we can either `siftDown` or `siftUp`, by sifting down we start from the root and compare it to its two children, then we replace it with the larger element of the two children, if both children are smaller then we stop, otherwise we continue sifting that element down until we reach a leaf node (or of course again, until that element is larger that both of its children).

Now we will only need to do that `n/2` times, because the number of leaves is `n/2`, and the leaves will satisfy the heap property when we finish heapifying the last element on the level before the last (before the leaves) - so we will be left with `n/2` elements to heapify.

Now if we use `siftUp`, we will start with the leaves, and eventually we will need to heapify all `n` elements.

My question is: when we use `siftDown`, aren't we basically doing two comparisons (comparing the element to its both children), instead of only one comparison when using `siftUp`, since we only compare that element to its one parent? If yes, wouldn't that mean that we're doubling the complexity and really ending up with the same exact complexity as sifting down?

Comment: I think the answers to this question apply. Maybe a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755721/how-can-building-a-heap-be-on-time-complexity

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Actually, building a heap with repeated calls of `siftDown` has a complexity of `O(n)` whereas building it with repeated calls of `siftUp` has a complexity of `O(nlogn)`.

This is due to the fact that when you use `siftDown`, the time taken by each call **decreases** with the depth of the node because these nodes are closer to the leaves. When you use `siftUp`, the number of swaps **increases** with the depth of the node because if you are at full depth, you may have to swap all the way to the root. As the number of nodes grows exponentially with the depth of the tree, using `siftUp` gives a more expensive algorithm.

Moreover, if you are using a Max-heap to do some sort of sorting where you pop the max element of the heap and then reheapify it, it's easier to do so by using `siftDown`. You can reheapify in `O(logn)` time by popping the max element, putting the last element at the root node (which was empty because you popped it) and then sifting it down all the way back to its correct spot.

Comment: How can you build a heap with SiftDown and complexity O(n) ?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755721/how-can-building-a-heap-be-on-time-complexity

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems to me that one should distinguish between average complexity and worst case complexity. Since average complexity of inserting an element in a heap is O(1), it seems to me that average complexity of `siftUp` is the same as `siftDown`. It seems to me that the difference is in the worst case : `siftUp` would be O(nlogn) whereas `siftDown` would be O(n) only. Can you please confirm ?

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew, the average complexity of inserting into a binary heap is O(logn) because generally, the item will be added to the end of the tree O(1) and then siftUp-ed to the correct position O(logn). The average complexity of `siftUp` will be, as you suggested, the same as `siftDown`. It turns out the worst-case complexity of sift will be O(logn) regardless of Up or Down. The only place for which there is a difference is specifically when heapifying for the reasons @alestanis went over.