# What is the time complexity of constructing a PriorityQueue from a collection?

Tags: java, collections, heap, priority-queue, binary-heap

What is the complexity of Java's PriorityQueue constructor with a `Collection`? 
I used the constructor:

```
PriorityQueue(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

Is the complexity O(n) or O(n*log(n))?

Comment: short answer, creating or constructing the heap [heapify] time complexity is: `O( N )`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The time complexity to initialize a `PriorityQueue` from a collection, even an unsorted one, is O(n). Internally this uses a procedure called `siftDown()` to "heapify" an array in-place. (This is also called pushdown in the literature.)

This is counterintuitive. It seems like inserting an element into a heap is O(log n) so inserting n elements results in O(n log n) complexity. This is true if you insert the elements one at a time. (Internally, inserting an individual element does this using `siftUp()`.)

Heapifying an individual element is certainly O(log n), but the "trick" of `siftDown()` is that as each element is processed, the number of elements that it has to be sifted past is continually decreasing. So the total complexity isn't n elements times log(n); it's the sum of n terms of the decreasing cost of sifting past the remaining elements.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13026026/1441122), and see also [this article](http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/node139.html) that works through the math.