# Max Heapify issue

Tags: java, heap, heapsort

I have been trying to debug this code for hours. I don't know why it is not rearranging the terms. I have tried everything I can think of. Can someone help? Thanks.

```
public void heapify(int i)  // utility routine to percolate down from index i
{
    printHeap();
    int left, r, min;
    Process tmp;

    left = lchild(i);           // left child
    r = rchild(i);                  // right child

    if(left < size() && A[left].compareTo(A[i])<0)      // find smallest child
        min = left;                 // save index of smaller child
    else
        min = i;

    if(r < size() && A[r].compareTo(A[min])<0)
        min = r;                // save index of smaller child

    if(min != i)                // swap and percolate, if necessary
    {
        tmp = A[i];             // exchange values at two indices
        A[i] = A[min];
        A[min] = tmp;
        heapify(min);

        // call heapify
    }// end if
printHeap();
}// end method heapify


private int lchild(int i) {
    return 2 * i + 1;
}

private int rchild(int i) {
    return 2 * i + 2;
}
```

Even when I call heapify on every element of the heap it doesn't work :/
Here is the compareTo. It is supposed to arrange max heap using priority first then if there is a tie it goes to a unique time arrived value.

```
public int compareTo(Process o) {
    int val;
    if (this.priority > o.getPriority()) {
        val = -1;
    } else if (this.priority == o.getPriority()) {
        if (this.arrivalTime < o.getArrivalTime()) { //Earlier time
            val = -1;
        } else {
            val = 1;
        }
    } else {
        val = 1;
    }

    return val;
}
```

Comment: It works when I try to run it. What is your test example where it doesn’t?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Are you trying to rearrange the items in an array (`A` in your example) so that they form a valid binary heap?

Comment: The SO would have to know; I took this comment to tell the story: “utility routine to percolate down from index i”, could be mistaken.

Comment: I was hoping that what it would do is organize the max heap if I run it for every element. Is this correct? If not how would I organize my entire max heap? Thanks.

Comment: I believe for your method to organize a heap correctly you will have to call it on all elements in the first half of the array *backwards*: `for (int index = A.length / 2; index >= 0; index--) { heapify(index); }`. Not sure about the exact place to start (+/- 1), and with length 0 the code I just gave will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, so at least adjust to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest known way to organize an array into a heap is called [Floyd's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap). You start at the middle of the array and move towards the root, sifting each item down as required. In your case:

```
for (int i = size()/2; i >= 0; --i)
{
    heapify(i);
}
```

You should be able to call the `heapify` function that you supplied.

To see how this works, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39020777/56778

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate you looking at it. It still doesn't seem to be sorting properly but I will keep looking at it.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate you looking at it. It still doesn't seem to be sorting properly but I will keep looking at it. Maybe it is. I could just be mis reading the debugger.

Comment: @ryBear Perhaps you should edit your question to show the actual code you're using, the input array, the expected output, and the actual output. That way we would have enough information to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It wasn't a problem in this method after all. Thanks everyone!