# Merge two minimum-heaps to one heap in efficiency?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap

Consider two min-heaps H1,H2 of size n1 and n2 respectively, such that every node in H2 is greater than every node of H1.

How can I merge this two heaps into one heap "H" , in O(n2) (not O(n^2)..)?
(Assume that the heaps represented in arrays of size > n1+n2)

Comment: Hint: If instead you had two sorted lists L1 and L2, with every element of L2 greater than every element of L1, how could you merge them into a single sorted list in O(n) (=O(n2)) time?  A heap is a bit like a sorted list that gets wider at the end; what might a corresponding action look like on two heaps?

Comment: @otus why delete the answer? It seems to fit the constraints.

Answer (score 4):

A heap can be constucted in linear time [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9755721/812912). This means you need only take all elements and construct a heap from all the elements to get linear complexity. However you can use a "more fancy" heap for instance [leftist heap](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~std3246/thesis/node29.html) and perform the merge operation even faster.