# Solution of the longest consecutive subsequence without using a hash structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, heap

When solving the longest consecutive subsequence problem (in linear time without sorting), the solution generally involves using a set library which normally internally uses hashing. For example, one typical solution:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class ArrayElements
{
    // Returns length of the longest consecutive subsequence
    static int findLongestConseqSubseq(int arr[],int n)
    {
        HashSet<Integer> S = new HashSet<Integer>();
        int ans = 0;

        // Hash all the array elements
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            S.add(arr[i]);

        // check each possible sequence from the start
        // then update optimal length
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        {
            // if current element is the starting
            // element of a sequence
            if (!S.contains(arr[i]-1))
            {
                // Then check for next elements in the
                // sequence
                int j = arr[i];
                while (S.contains(j))
                    j++;

                // update  optimal length if this length
                // is more
                if (ans<j-arr[i])
                    ans = j-arr[i];
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }

    // Testing program
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int arr[] =  {1, 9, 3, 10, 4, 20, 2};
        int n = arr.length;
        System.out.println("Length of the Longest consecutive subsequence is " +
                           findLongestConseqSubseq(arr,n));
    }
}

// This code is contributed by Aakash Hasija
```

Here a `HashSet` is used.

Is there a way to do this without using a hash? In theory the problem should be solvable using union-find which requires a heap. Therefore, the problem reduces to building exploiting a heap without using a hash. How can this be done?

Comment: to fill a heap is not linear time... it is O(n log n)

Comment: If there is an upper and a lower level on `arr[i]` you can use an array of booleans instead.

Comment: @Thomas Building a heap is linear time, already an SO answered question: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755721/how-can-building-a-heap-be-on-time-complexity