# My Dijkstra's algorithm implementation does not return shortest path

Tags: javascript, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I tried to implement the Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm in JavaScript, and tested it with multiple examples.

I am using this graph to see how it would behave:

[image]

If I want to find the shortest path from A to I, the result should be [A, D, C, F, G, H, I] with distance equal to 10.

But my implementation returns the path as [A, B, E, J, F, G, H, I] with distance of 14.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```js
const graph = {
    A: {B: 3, C: 4, D: 2},
    B: {A: 3, D: 6, E: 1},
    C: {A: 4, D: 1, F: 3},
    D: {A: 2, B: 6, C: 1, E: 5},
    E: {B: 1, D: 5, J: 1},
    F: {C: 3, G: 2, J: 5},
    G: {F: 2, H: 1, I: 3},
    H: {G: 1, I: 1, X: 2},
    I: {G: 3, H: 1, X: 8},
    J: {E: 1, F: 5, X: 6},
    X: {H: 2, I: 8, J: 6},
};

// The class Dsp:

class Dsp {
  constructor() {
    //Previous node after update of distance
    this.prev = {};
    //Distances of each node
    this.distances = {};
    //Array of unvisited neighbors
    this.unvisitedn = [];
    //Path of visited nodes from first to final node
    this.path = [];
  }

  findsp(graph, start, end) {

    //Register graph data 
    this.registerGraphData(graph, start);

    //Set the starting node as the current node
    let cn = start;

    //While there are unvisited nodes
    while (this.unvisitedn.length > 0) {
      //Mark the currentNode as visited
      this.markAsVisited(cn);

      //Compare distance from current node to unvisited neighbors
      let nodes = this.compareNodeDistances(graph, cn);

      //Update neighbor distance
      this.updateNodeDistances(nodes, cn);

      //Compare each unvisited neighbor and choose the one with the lowest distances
      //Set the choosed node as the new current node
      cn = this.selectNextNode(graph, cn);
    }

    return this.generatePath(start, end);
  }

  registerGraphData(graph, start) {

    //Set starting weight for all nodes
    const higherWeight = 10000;

    //For each node in the graph
    for (let node in graph) {
      //If the node is the starting node 
      if (node == start)
        //Set starting weight as 0
        this.distances[node] = 0;
      //else set the higherWeight
      else
        this.distances[node] = higherWeight;

      //Add to the unvisited nodes
      this.unvisitedn.push(node);
    }

    console.log(this.distances);
    console.log(this.unvisitedn);
  }

  markAsVisited(cn) {

    console.log('Visiting', cn);

    let index = this.unvisitedn.indexOf(cn);
    this.unvisitedn.splice(index, 1);
  }

  getUnvisitedNeighbors(graph, cn) {

    //All current node neighbors
    let nbs = graph[cn];
    let unbs = [];

    for (let nb in nbs) {
      if (this.unvisitedn.includes(nb))
        unbs.push(nb);
    }

    console.log(cn, 'Unvisited neighbors:', unbs);

    return unbs;
  }

  compareNodeDistances(graph, cn) {

    let unbs = this.getUnvisitedNeighbors(graph, cn);

    //new distances
    let newDistances = {};

    //For all currentNode neighbors
    for (let nb of unbs) { //Substituted unbs

      //Neighbor Weight
      let nbw = graph[cn][nb];
      //console.log('Neighbor weight', nbw);

      //neighbor distance
      let nbd = this.distances[nb];
      //console.log('Neighbor distance', nbd);

      //current node distance
      let cnd = this.distances[cn];
      //console.log('Current node distance', cnd);

      //If the neighbor distance > current node distance + neighbor weight
      if (nbd > cnd + nbw)
        newDistances[nb] = cnd + nbw;
    }

    console.log('new distances:', newDistances);

    return newDistances;
  }

  updateNodeDistances(nodes, cn) {

    //Update distances for each neighbor that was compared
    for (let node in nodes) {
      console.log(nodes);


      this.distances[node] = nodes[node];
      this.prev[node] = cn;
    }

    console.log("Node distances after update", this.distances);
    console.log("Node previous nodes after update", this.prev);
  }

  selectNextNode(graph, cn) {
    let unbs = this.getUnvisitedNeighbors(graph, cn);
    let mind = 100000;
    let nextn = null;

    //If there are unvisited neighbors
    if (unbs.length > 0) {
      for (let nb of unbs) {
        if (this.distances[nb] < mind) {
          mind = this.distances[nb];
          nextn = nb;
        }
      }
    } else {
      nextn = this.unvisitedn[0];
    }

    return nextn;
  }

  generatePath(start, end) {

    let cn = end;
    let path = {};
    let nodes = [];

    while (cn !== start) {
      nodes.push(cn);
      cn = this.prev[cn];
    }

    nodes.push(start);
    nodes.reverse();

    path['nodes'] = nodes;
    path['distance'] = this.distances[end];

    return path;
  }
}

let shp = new Dsp();

console.log(shp.findsp(graph, 'A', 'I'));
```

I would like to understand what´s wrong with the steps I programmed.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some additional step, or consideration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not performing a best-first search. Your code really performs a depth-first search, where you just optimise which unvisited *neighbor* you will choose from the *current* node. But you should take the node with the minimum distance from among *all* unvisited nodes, not just among the neighbors of the *current* node.

See also step 6 of the algorithm description on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Algorithm):

> 6. Otherwise, select the **unvisited node** that is marked with the smallest tentative distance, set it as the new "current node"

So the problem is in `selectNextNode`. It could be corrected to this:

```
selectNextNode(graph, cn) {
    let mindist = Infinity;
    let best;
    for (let node of this.unvisitedn) {
        if (this.distances[node] < mindist) {
            mindist = this.distances[node];
            best = node;
        }
    }
    return best;
}
```

However, this is a naive implementation, as in each round you have to find the minimum again: this makes the algorithm non-optimal. A true Dijkstra algorithm will use a priority queue, such as a heap, which makes this lookup more efficient.

## Implementation with Heap

Unfortunately JavaScript does not (yet) provide a native heap implementation, so we have to throw our own or reference a library. I took the implementation from my answer to [Efficient way to implement Priority Queue in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66511107/5459839). See there for more details on that implementation.

I think the implementation of the shortest path algorithm does not warrant the use of a class. A function like your `findsp` should be enough.

So here it is:

```js
/* MinHeap minimised - taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66511107/5459839 */
const MinHeap={siftDown(h,i=0,v=h[i]){if(i<h.length){let k=v[0];while(1){let j=i*2+1;if(j+1<h.length&&h[j][0]>h[j+1][0])j++;if(j>=h.length||k<=h[j][0])break;h[i]=h[j];i=j;}h[i]=v}},heapify(h){for(let i=h.length>>1;i--;)this.siftDown(h,i);return h},pop(h){return this.exchange(h,h.pop())},exchange(h,v){if(!h.length)return v;let w=h[0];this.siftDown(h,0,v);return w},push(h,v){let k=v[0],i=h.length,j;while((j=(i-1)>>1)>=0&&k<h[j][0]){h[i]=h[j];i=j}h[i]=v;return h}};

function DijkstraShortestPath(graph, start, end) {
    // Heap with one entry: distance is 0 at start, and there is no previous.
    let heap = [[0, start, null]]; 
    let prev = {};
    
    while (heap.length) {
        let [distance, current, cameFrom] = MinHeap.pop(heap);
        if (current in prev) continue; // Already visited
        prev[current] = cameFrom; // Mark as visited
        if (current == end) { // Found!
            // Reconstruct path
            let path = [];
            while (current) {
                path.push(current);
                current = prev[current];
            }
            path.reverse();
            return { path, distance };
        }
        // Push unvisited neighbors on the heap
        for (let [neighbor, edge] of Object.entries(graph[current])) {
            if (!(neighbor in prev)) MinHeap.push(heap, [distance + edge, neighbor, current]);
        }
    }
}

// Demo:
const graph = {
    A: {B: 3, C: 4, D: 2},
    B: {A: 3, D: 6, E: 1},
    C: {A: 4, D: 1, F: 3},
    D: {A: 2, B: 6, C: 1, E: 5},
    E: {B: 1, D: 5, J: 1},
    F: {C: 3, G: 2, J: 5},
    G: {F: 2, H: 1, I: 3},
    H: {G: 1, I: 1, X: 2},
    I: {G: 3, H: 1, X: 8},
    J: {E: 1, F: 5, X: 6},
    X: {H: 2, I: 8, J: 6},
}

console.log(DijkstraShortestPath(graph, 'A', 'I'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this code for Dijkstra Algo

```
const top = 0;
const parent = (i) => ((i + 1) >>> 1) - 1;
const left = (i) => (i << 1) + 1;
const right = (i) => (i + 1) << 1;
let g = new Array(100005);
let vis = new Array(100005);
class PriorityQueue {
  constructor(comparator = (a, b) => a[0] < b[0]) {
    this._heap = [];
    this._comparator = comparator;
  }
  size() {
    return this._heap.length;
  }
  isEmpty() {
    return this.size() == 0;
  }
  peek() {
    return this._heap[top];
  }
  push(...values) {
    values.forEach((value) => {
      this._heap.push(value);
      this._siftUp();
    });
    return this.size();
  }
  pop() {
    const poppedValue = this.peek();
    const bottom = this.size() - 1;
    if (bottom > top) {
      this._swap(top, bottom);
    }
    this._heap.pop();
    this._siftDown();
    return poppedValue;
  }
  replace(value) {
    const replacedValue = this.peek();
    this._heap[top] = value;
    this._siftDown();
    return replacedValue;
  }
  _greater(i, j) {
    return this._comparator(this._heap[i], this._heap[j]);
  }
  _swap(i, j) {
    [this._heap[i], this._heap[j]] = [this._heap[j], this._heap[i]];
  }
  _siftUp() {
    let node = this.size() - 1;
    while (node > top && this._greater(node, parent(node))) {
      this._swap(node, parent(node));
      node = parent(node);
    }
  }
  _siftDown() {
    let node = top;
    while (
      (left(node) < this.size() && this._greater(left(node), node)) ||
      (right(node) < this.size() && this._greater(right(node), node))
    ) {
      let maxChild =
        right(node) < this.size() && this._greater(right(node), left(node))
          ? right(node)
          : left(node);
      this._swap(node, maxChild);
      node = maxChild;
    }
  }
}

function clean(n) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
    g[i] = [];
    console.log(g);
    vis[i] = 0;
    console.log(vis);
  }
}

function make_graph(edges) {
  for (let i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
    let it = edges[i];
    let x = it[0];
    let y = it[1];
    let w = it[2];
    g[x].push([w, y]);
    g[y].push([w, x]);
  }
}
// module.exports =
//   //param A : integer
//   //param B : array of array of integers
//   //param C : integer
//   //return a array of integers
function solve(n, edges, source) {
  clean(n);
  make_graph(edges);
  let distance = new Array(n).fill(Infinity);
  let q = new PriorityQueue();
  distance[source] = 0;
  q.push([0, source]);
  while (q.size() > 0) {
    let p = q.pop();
    let x = p[1];
    if (vis[x] == 1) continue;
    vis[x] = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < g[x].length; ++i) {
      let y = g[x][i][1];
      let w = g[x][i][0];
      if (distance[x] + w < distance[y]) {
        distance[y] = distance[x] + w;
        q.push([distance[y], y]);
      }
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (distance[i] == Infinity) distance[i] = -1;
  }
  return distance;
}

let A = 6;
let B = [
  [0, 4, 9],
  [3, 4, 6],
  [1, 2, 1],
  [2, 5, 1],
  [2, 4, 5],
  [0, 3, 7],
  [0, 1, 1],
  [4, 5, 7],
  [0, 5, 1],
];
let C = 4;

console.log(solve(A, B, C));
```