# priority queue question. priority is undefined in while loop. how to enqueue element to queue?

Tags: javascript, priority-queue, heap, min-heap, max-heap

doing a priority queue as a min-heap in javascript. console keeps returning priority is undefined in the while loop. what is the problem? / how to enqueue element to queue?

```js
//min-heap
class PriorityQueue {
  constructor(){
    this.values = [];
  }
  enqueue(value, priority){
    let newNode = new Node(value, priority);
    this.values.push(newNode);
    this.bubbleUp();
  }
  bubbleUp(){
    let childIndex = this.values.length - 1;
    let parentIndex = Math.floor((childIndex - 1) / 2);
    let childElement = this.values[childIndex].priority;
    let parentElement = this.values[parentIndex].priority;

    while(childElement < parentElement){
      let temp = this.values[childIndex];
      this.values[childIndex] = this.values[parentIndex];
      this.values[parentIndex] = temp;

      childIndex = parentIndex;
      parentIndex = Math.floor((childIndex - 1) / 2);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One scenario you're not considering is when the heap has only one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues in your `bubbleUp` method:

- The `while` loop never updates the variables that are compared in the loop condition.
- The processing should detect when `parentIndex` is no longer valid, i.e. when `childIndex` is the root, and then exit.

Here is a correction:

```
  bubbleUp(){
    let childIndex = this.values.length - 1;
    let parentIndex = Math.floor((childIndex - 1) / 2);

    while (childIndex > 0 && this.values[childIndex].priority < this.values[parentIndex].priority){
      let temp = this.values[childIndex];
      this.values[childIndex] = this.values[parentIndex];
      this.values[parentIndex] = temp;

      childIndex = parentIndex;
      parentIndex = Math.floor((childIndex - 1) / 2);
    }
  }
```

For full implementations, have a look at [Efficient way to implement Priority Queue in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42919469/5459839), where I have also posted [my preferred implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66511107/5459839).

Comment: thanks much appreciated, i have a question on how to dequeue-ing if you don't mind looking at it. i know there's no boundaries, but i am updating the variable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73954798/min-priority-queue-question-dequeue-doesnt-work-says-undefined-for-priority