# min priority queue question. dequeue doesn't work. says undefined for priority

Tags: javascript, data-structures, tree, priority-queue, min-heap

this is a min-priority queue in javascript. i can't get dequeue to work. it says in console **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'priority')**. i'm able to insert all the nodes into an array. when i console the array after dequeue-ing, it returns the correct number of nodes. i just can't return the oldNode after the 1st oldNode.

```js
//min-heap
class PriorityQueue {
  constructor(){
    this.values = [];
  }
  enqueue(value, priority){
    let newNode = new Node(value, priority);
    this.values.push(newNode);
    this.bubbleUp();
  }
  bubbleUp(){
    let childIndex = this.values.length - 1;
    let parentIndex = Math.floor((childIndex - 1) / 2);

    while(childIndex > 0 && this.values[childIndex].priority < this.values[parentIndex].priority){
      let temp = this.values[childIndex];
      this.values[childIndex] = this.values[parentIndex];
      this.values[parentIndex] = temp;

      childIndex = parentIndex;
      parentIndex = Math.floor((childIndex - 1) / 2);
    }
  }
  dequeue(){
    if(!this.values.length) return null;
    //swap root and highest number element
    this.swap(0, this.values.length - 1);
    let oldNode = this.values.pop();

    let parent = 0, childLeft = 1, childRight = 2;
    let min = Math.min(this.values[childLeft].priority, this.values[childRight].priority);

    while(this.values[parent].priority > min){
      let child = this.values[childLeft].priority === min ? childLeft : childRight;
      this.swap(parent, child);
      parent = child;

      //get children of current parent
      childLeft = parent * 2 + 1;
      childRight = parent * 2 + 2;

      min = Math.min(this.values[childLeft].priority, this.values[childRight].priority);
    }
    return oldNode;
  }
  swap(index1, index2){
    [this.values[index1], this.values[index2]] = [this.values[index2], this.values[index1]];
  }
}

class Node{
  constructor(value, priority){
    this.value = value;
    this.priority = priority;
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be doing any boundary checking when you call `values[childLeft]` and `values[childRight]`. Are you sure the error is saying the priority is undefined, or is it saying that it can't find the property "priority" of `undefined`?

Comment: You have an error in `swap`, should be `[this.values[index1], this.values[index2]] = [this.values[index1], this.values[index2]];`

Comment: @welbog i think you're right. there is no boundary checking when i trickle down. how would i be able to incorporate boundaries in my while statement? thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array Out of Bounds: Comparison with undefined, or length check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728424/array-out-of-bounds-comparison-with-undefined-or-length-check)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- The `swap` method isn't swapping: the indexes should be reversed on one of the two sides of the assignment.
- The `dequeue` method is making accesses to the `values` array that are beyond its length. For instance, if there is only one element in the heap (after the pop), then `childLeft` and `childRight` are both out of range, and `this.values[childLeft].priority` will attempt to get the `priority` property from an undefined value, which leads to the error you got. But even if the `values` array has more entries, this situation can occur in the loop as well. When `childLeft` and `childRight` get updated values, the last statement in the loop body will not check whether this indices are still within the valid range.

To avoid the code repetition you already have (the two statements before the loop look the similar to the last two statements in the loop body), I would actually make that range check your loop condition, and make the condition you currently use a check that is made half-way the loop body.

Here is a correction:

```
  dequeue(){
    if (!this.values.length) return null;
    //swap root and highest number element
    this.swap(0, this.values.length - 1);
    let oldNode = this.values.pop();

    let parent = 0;
    while (parent * 2 + 1 < this.values.length) { // While the parent has at least one child
        // get child(ren) of current parent
        let child = parent * 2 + 1; // right child is just next to it. No need for an extra variable.
        // if there is a right child(!), take it when it has a lesser rank than the left child
        if (child + 1 < this.values.length && this.values[child].priority > this.values[child + 1].priority) {
            child++; // Choose the right child, as it has the lesser rank
        }
        // Exit when parent has a lesser rank than its child(ren)
        if (this.values[parent].priority < this.values[child].priority) break;
        this.swap(parent, child);
        parent = child;
    }
    return oldNode;
  }
  swap(index1, index2){
    [this.values[index1], this.values[index2]] = [this.values[index2], this.values[index1]]; // fixed
  }
```