# How to use built in priority queue in javascript?

Tags: data-structures, priority-queue, heap

How can we use built in priority  queue in javascript

In chrome I am not able to run built in pq in javascript

Comment: Strange that you have marked an answer as accepted that sorts the whole queue every time an item is pushed to it. This could hardly count as "native", and it is not even efficient.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**JavaScript Task Queue Implementation: Prioritizing and Optimizing Code Execution**

```js
const taskQueue = [];

function enqueueTask(task, priority = 0) {
  taskQueue.push({ task, priority });
  taskQueue.sort((a, b) => a.priority - b.priority);
}

async function processQueue() {
  while (taskQueue.length > 0) {
    const { task, priority } = taskQueue.shift();
    const startTime = performance.now();
    await task();
    const endTime = performance.now();
    const executionTime = endTime - startTime;
    console.log(`Task with priority ${priority} executed in ${executionTime.toFixed(2)} ms`);
  }
}

function task1() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Executing Task 1");
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function task2() {
  console.log("Executing Task 2");
}

function task3() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Executing Task 3");
      resolve();
    }, 1500);
  });
}

function task4() {
  console.log("Executing Task 4");
}

enqueueTask(() => task1(), 2);
enqueueTask(() => task2(), 1);
enqueueTask(() => task3(), 3);
enqueueTask(() => task4(), 0);

processQueue();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing "built in" in JavaScript that bears the name priority queue. The native thing that comes closest is a plain object with *array-index* keys.

That comes with some limitations:

- The keys of the priority queue have to be unsigned integers in the 32-bit range
- The priority queue cannot hold two items with the same key unless you add additional logic to deal with that.

Here is how that would work:

```js
function pqInsert(pq, key, value) {
    if (String(Math.abs(+key | 0)) != String(key)) throw "Key must be unsigned 32 bit integer";
    if (pq[key] !== undefined) throw "Duplicate key";
    pq[key] = value;
}

function pqLeastKey(pq) {
    for (const key in pq) { // Iterate numeric keys in order
        return key; // Exit in first iteration
    }
}

function pqExtract(pq) {
    const key = pqLeastKey(pq);
    const value = pq[key]; // Get value of least key
    delete pq[key]; // Remove it
    return [key, value];
}

const pq = {};

// I/O handling
const [keyInput, valueInput, addButton, removeButton, br, output] =
          document.body.children;
addButton.onclick = () => {
    pqInsert(pq, keyInput.value, valueInput.value);
    keyInput.value = valueInput.value = "";
    output.textContent = JSON.stringify(pq, null, 2);
}
removeButton.onclick = () => {
    [keyInput.value, valueInput.value] = pqExtract(pq);
    output.textContent = JSON.stringify(pq, null, 2);
};
```

```css
input { width: 5em }
```

```html
Key: <input type="number" min="0"> Value: <input> <button>Add</button>
<button>Extract minimum</button><br>
Queue: <pre>{}</pre>
```

That's as close as you can get to a *native* priority queue behaviour in JavaScript. Alternatively, you can of course add a library, or throw your own implementation of a priority queue. For instance, at [Efficient way to implement Priority Queue in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42919752/5459839) you'll find some implementations. I also posted [my heap implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66511107/5459839) there.