# Time complexity of the creation of a Balanced binary search tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

Although the time complexity of building a min heap looks like O(nlogn), it can be proved that it is [O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755721/how-can-building-a-heap-be-on-time-complexity).

Why can't we apply the same logic and say the time complexity of a balanced binary search tree is also O(n).

Comment: (Time complexity of building a balanced BST depends on input data, too:   Ο(n) *if* your n input items are ordered (and, depending on details, randomly accessible).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the fact that BST provides order, while heap only ensures that element is greater than those below (for max-heap), the complexity of building the heap depends on the building strategy. This [wiki image](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Binary_heap_bottomup_vs_topdown.svg) demonstrates it clearly.

If you use `siftDown` (bottom-up) approach, complexity is `O(n)`, while with `siftUp` is `O(nlogn)`, just like in BST.

> Why can't we apply the same logic and say the time complexity of a
>   balanced binary search tree is also O(n)?

Bottom-up approach for building a heap is not applicable for BST unless the input list is already sorted, but in this case you already have `O(nlogn)` complexity because of sorting.

Comment: @Mikic, You have not added image.

Comment: Understood. Thanks :)