# If heapify(x) takes O(n) how can heappush() take O(log n)?

Tags: python

Let's say there is a list `arr` with `n` elements.
Then, `heapq.heapify(arr)` takes `O(n)`.
But I learned `heapq.heappush(arr, element)` will take `O(log n)`.
Isn't `heapify` same as calling `heappush` `n` times?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755721/how-can-building-a-heap-be-on-time-complexity)

Comment: Also check the [source code for CPython's `heapify` and `_siftup`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/heapq.py#L168)

Comment: Calling `heappush()` `n` times would be one way to implement `heapify`, but a cleverer implementation is used - see links already given.