# Time and Space complexity of a Balanced Binary Search Tree

Tags: time-complexity, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search, space-complexity

What is computational complexity(time and space complexity) of building a Balanced Binary Search Tree?

Comment: What do you think? Why?

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity to build a BST with `n` nodes is `O(n*log(n))`.

Why? You need to go through each of the `n` nodes to insert it into the tree. Now to insert one node it would take `log(n)` comparisons.

So the overall time complexity to insert `n` nodes in a binary search tree would be `O(n*log(n))`

Answer (score 1):

It takes O(log n) time to insert one node into a balanced binary search tree, so n nodes can be inserted to build a tree in O(n log n) time.

It remains to be shown that there isn't a better way to build the tree - for example, it also takes O(log n) time to insert an element into a heap, but there is [a cleverer algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755721/how-can-building-a-heap-be-on-time-complexity) which builds a heap of size n in O(n) time. However, Ω(n log n) is a lower bound for any comparison-sorting algorithm, so there cannot be an asymptotically faster way to build a BST, because you can do a comparison sort by building a BST and then [traversing it in order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).