# heappush() and heapify() gives different output for same input in python when using heapq, error?

Tags: python, heap

```
import heapq

heap = []   # creates an empty heap
item = [20, 4, 8, 10, 5, 7, 6, 2, 9]
for i in item:
    heapq.heappush(heap, i)  # pushes a new item on the heap

print('Heap obtained from heappush() : ', heap)

same_item = [20, 4, 8, 10, 5, 7, 6, 2, 9]
heapq.heapify(same_item)  # transforms list into a heap, in-place, in linear time

print('Heap obtained from heapify() : ', same_item)
```

My understanding is both ***heappush()*** and ***heapify()*** should give the same output whereas output says otherwise.

```
Heap obtained from heappush() :  [2, 4, 6, 5, 10, 8, 7, 20, 9]
Heap obtained from heapify() :  [2, 4, 6, 9, 5, 7, 8, 10, 20]
```

Thank you in advance.

**Edited**: Thanks to @shx2's answer as I was able to verify the correct functionality. Code to verify.

```
print('\nPopping elements 1 by 1 to very the real structure obtained from heappush() and heapify()\n')

print('First from heap obtained from heappush() : ', end='')
for i in range(len(item)):
    print(heapq.heappop(heap), end=' ')

print('\nNow from heap obtained from heapify() : ', end='')
for i in range(len(item)):
    print(heapq.heappop(same_item), end=' ')
```

Answer (score 7):

Not an error. Both produce valid heaps.

> Heaps are binary trees for which every parent node has a value less than or equal to any of its children.

This ordering is not uniquely defined.

In other words, a heap is not a sorted structure, so there are many different orderings which form valid heaps.

To verify, run a [`heappop`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappop)-loop on both, and check they both return the items in sorted order.

Comment: Thank you @shx2 whereas don't you think the way I was printing the heap list should also reflect the same i.e should show the sorted list.

Comment: @Arpit-Gole In both cases the list isn't sorted.  Also, think about it as internal private representation.  There are many different alternative internal representations.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @shx2's answer, the `heapify` function does not work by doing `heappush` for each item; it uses a different, more efficient algorithm. The `heappush` function takes O(log *n*) time, so doing it *n* times would take O(*n* log *n*) time, but the `heapify` algorithm actually works in O(*n*) time.

The algorithm for building a heap in linear time is described in [this other Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9755721/12299000).