# What is the time complexity of using max heap to solve "Find the K-th largest number in the array" problem?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, heap

"Find the K-th largest number in the array" problem:

```
inputs: [3,2,1,5,6,4], k = 2
outputs: 5

inputs: [3,2,3,1,2,4,5,5,6], k = 4
outputs: 4
```

I know that this problem can be soleved with `quick select` and `min heap` algorithms. However, what I'm focusing here is using `max heap`. The steps is the following:

```
1. Build max heap form the whole given array, inplace.
2. Iterate k times. In each iteration, Take and remove the heap top.
3. The last heap top taken at the k-th iteration is the result.
```

Below is the code in cpp:

```
void swap(vector<int>& nums, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = nums[i];
    nums[i] = nums[j];
    nums[j] = tmp;
}

void heapify_down(vector<int>& nums, int parent_idx, int end_idx) {
    int left_idx = parent_idx * 2 + 1, right_idx = left_idx + 1;
    while (left_idx <= end_idx) {
        int largeset_idx = parent_idx;
        if (nums[left_idx] > nums[largeset_idx]) largeset_idx = left_idx;
        if (right_idx <= end_idx && nums[right_idx] > nums[largeset_idx]) largeset_idx = right_idx;
        if (largeset_idx != parent_idx) {
            swap(nums, parent_idx, largeset_idx);
            parent_idx = largeset_idx;
            left_idx = parent_idx * 2 + 1;
            right_idx = left_idx + 1;
        }
        else {
            return ;
        }
    }
}

void build_heap(vector<int>& nums) {
    for (int i = nums.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) heapify_down(nums, i, nums.size() - 1);
}

int findKthLargest(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
    build_heap(nums);
    int cnt = 0, res, cur_end = nums.size() - 1;
    while (cnt != k) {
        res = nums[0];
        cnt += 1;
        swap(nums, 0, cur_end);
        cur_end -= 1;
        heapify_down(nums, 0, cur_end);
    }

    return res;
}
```

What is the time complextity of this method? I'm using bottom-up approach in the first step, this step should be O(n). However, the while loop makes me confused. The loop execute k times, each loop will call `heapify_down` which is O(log(n)) comlexity. So is the overall complexity `O(n + k * log(n)) = O(max(n, k * log(n)))`? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `build_heap` alone is `O(n*log n)` already (assuming you are correct in assessing that `heapify_down` is `O(log n)`; `build_heap` calls it `n` times).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik tighter bound for `build_heap` will be O(n) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755721/how-can-building-a-heap-be-on-time-complexity

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm for people skimming the first line. Changing from min to max doesn't really matter (since you're looking for kth largest you'd just use max, but it's the same otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

Building a heap, if you do it right, is `O(n)` and removing the top is `O(log n)` and with `k` being unbound it could be `n`.

So overall it is `O(n + k * log n) == O(n + n * log n) == O(n log n)`.

Don't you have some more information, like `k < log n` or something?

---

When building your heap don't use `heapify_down`, because that results in O(n * log n). Instead first ignore the last element if the heap has odd size. Then start at `i = size / 2 - 1` and swap `i`, `2 * i` and `2 * i + 1` around so the largest is at `i`. Repeat till `i-- = 0`. If the size was odd add the last element to the heap.

Comment: The only constraint upon k is that it is less than n. So the upper bound of the time complexity will no more than `O(n * log n)` and this should be the time complexity for this solution. Am I right? In terms of `heapify_down`, I think I implement the same idea as you described. The only difference is that, I start at the end of the array, and those leaves are called but not go into the while loop. I think the time complexity of my `heapify_down` is still `O(n)`.

Comment: If it is then you did it wrong. It should be `O(log n)` otherwise the total becomes `O(n^2)`.